# I want to make a rectangle slowly extend across the screen taking exactly 1 second in android

Tags: android, graphics, timing

Basically, I am making a rectangle that represents charge on your weapon. I want a green rectangle to advance over a red one after a certain amount of time. My issue is the timing. I have no clue how to do any timing anything in android.I'm fairly new so don't use too many things I might not understand. All of this is within a view. I researched threading and handlers, but just got confused.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [View Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View) if you want to support pre 3.0 without using a library. OR [Property Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html) if targetting 3.0+ is ok.

I have more experience with the View Animations and I can tell you that the Scale animation is the one you'd be looking for. Make your X scale to 100% its size perhaps would get the job done.